# Strange error: creating a file in the external storage turns a resource id into an invalid id

Tags: android, android-resources

I have some activities, one of which creates some kind of object which is serialized to a file, and an other activity which should show a list of serialized objects in the data directory(and has a "Create new" button that starts the activity to create a new object)

When the directory is empty, all works fine and there is no crash. Actually, the directory does not have to be empty. The files that should be shown all end with a particular extension and the main application filters them out. If I change the extension of the file the application does not crash.

When I create one of these objects, the object is correctly saved into `/sdcard/data/org.my.package/files/the_object_file` but, at this point, if I open the activity that should show the list of serialized objects I get an `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`.

I must also say that these activity use fragments and the exception occurs in a piece of code which looks like this one:

```
public class ShowObjectsActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    public static final int SHOW_CREATE_OBJECT_ACTIVITY = 3;

    public static final int CREATE_OBJECT = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 1;
    public static final int LOAD_OBJECT = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 2;

    public static final String THE_OBJECT = "org.my.package.THE_OBJECT";

    private MainObjectsFragment mainFragment = null;

    private String[] objectNames = null;
    private ObjectSerializer serializer = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.objects);

        if (mainFragment == null) {
            mainFragment = new MainObjectsFragment();

            // Fails on the following .add
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.objects_fragment_container, mainFragment).commit();
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        serializer = new ObjectSerializer(
                intent.getStringExtra(TheMainActivity.APP_FILES_DIRECTORY));
        this.objectNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra(
                TheMainActivity.OBJECTS_NAMES);
        if (this.objectNames == null) {
            this.objectNames = new String[0];
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        // Set the ArrayAdapter for the ListView
        mainFragment.setObjectsAdapter(this,
                                       this.objectNames);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == SHOW_CREATE_OBJECT_ACTIVITY) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                setResult(CREATE_OBJECT, intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    public void createNewObject(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewObjectActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SHOW_CREATE_OBJECT_ACTIVITY);
    }


}
```

And the `objects.xml` layout file is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/objects_fragment_container"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The method of `TheMainActivity`, which launches the activity that should show the list of objects, looks like this:

```
public void showObjectsActivity(View view) {

    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.external_storage_not_available_title);
        dialog.setMessage(R.string.external_storage_not_available_msg);
        dialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Empty
            }
        });

        dialog.create().show();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowObjectsActivity.class);
        String app_files_directory = getTheFilesDir();
        // When the file is in the directory the following is the array I'd expect.
        // an array with the names of the objects
        intent.putExtra(OBJECTS_NAMES,
                        new ObjectSerializer(
                                app_files_directory).listObjectNames());
        intent.putExtra(APP_FILES_DIRECTORY, app_files_directory);

        startActivityForResult(intent, SHOW_OBJECTS);
    }
}
```

Note that the `MainObjectsFragment` `onCreateView` doesn't do anything related to the names array. Also the crash in the `ShowObjectsActivity` happens *before* the intent is touched at all.

Here's the traceback:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050002 type #0x12 is not valid
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2297)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:988)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:349)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1523)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1786)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:705)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:762)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1639)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1318)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1285)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1161)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1078)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1285)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1161)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1078)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1285)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1161)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1078)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1285)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1161)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1078)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1181)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1906)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4070)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:906)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:664)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1186):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  197):   Force finishing activity org.my.package/.ShowObjectsActivity
W/ActivityManager(  197):   Force finishing activity org.my.package/.TheMainActivity
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why does the presence of a file in a data directory cause a `ResourceNotFound` error?

---

**Edit:** I think I'm starting to understand how the error happens. The `MainObjectsFragment`'s layout contains a `ListView`. I have provided a `TextView` to show if the view is empty, and the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/main_objects_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/no_objects_available"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/new_object_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_object"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:onClick="createNewObject" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(IntelliJ states that the above XML has an unbound namespace of `''`. All the other files looks exactly the same and do not trigger the warning. I don't know whether there is something wrong in my file or if it is a bug in IntelliJ).

At first I thought that maybe the error was caused by the fact that, if the adapter is empty then the `TextView` is shown and not the `ListView`. But the code of the fragment *always* searches for the `ListView`.

I checked the generated `R.java` file and it *does* contain the `id` with the correct name.

---

I post here also the code for the `MainObjectsFragment`:

```
public class MainObjectsFragment extends Fragment {

    public ListView objectsList;
    public Button newObjectButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_objects_fragment, container, false);
        this.objectsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_objects_view);

        // Before I only placed this empty TextView via xml. This does not change
        // the error at all.
        TextView emptyText = new TextView(getActivity());
        emptyText.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.no_objects_available));
        emptyText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
        emptyText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        this.objectsList.setEmptyView(emptyText);
        this.objectsList.setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.id.main_objects_view,
                                         new String[0])
        );
        this.newObjectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.new_object_button);
        return view;
    }

    public void setCharsAdapter(Context ctx, String[] data) {

        this.objectsList.setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.id.main_objects_view, data));
    }
}
```

Comment: i'd say it's in mainobjectfragment. also you can look in your R.java what #0x7f050002 is.

Comment: if it's a listfragment, you need an @android:id/list in it

Comment: @njzk2 I never mentioned a `ListFragment`, so it's not. It's a plain `Fragment` which has a `ListView` in it. When I have time I'll try to use a `ListFragment` instead, but I'd like to understand this error anyway.

Comment: i assumed from the existence of @android:id/empty in the layout

Comment: also, did you checked what is #0x7f050002 in R.java ?

Comment: @njzk2 Oh, I forgot to post it here. It's the `ListView` which is part of the fragment.

Comment: there definitely has to be someting in MainObjectsFragment.java

Comment: @njzk2 I've updated my question with the code for `MainObjectsFragment`.

Comment: ArrayAdapter expect the id of a layout file, not the id of your list.